# How can an American get a Maestro Debit Card?

Tags: us-citizens, payment-cards, netherlands

I am an American and I plan on traveling to the Netherlands periodically over the next few years.

I was recently there and had to use a hodgepodge of credit card, debit cards, cash and worst of all having a colleague pay and then I reimbursed them with cash.

For instance, some company cafeterias only accept credit/debit card.  Also, train stations have unmanned kiosks for buying tickets.  Also, some vending machines are Maestro card only (no cash).

I tried using my American credit cards that have a chip, but they were not recognized by the cafeteria nor vending machine.

I would like to get a Maestro card so that I have a reliable way to pay.

How can I, as an American, get a Maestro card?

The Maestro card has a logo that looks very similar to a MasterCard, but it is not a MasterCard.

I would also consider another credit/debit card if it had the same acceptance as the Maestro card, but it seems Maestro is the most popular.

I would also consider a prepaid Maestro card if I can get my money back off of it easily and I can get a charge history for submitting an expense report.

[edit] removed references to Maestro as a credit card.  Added my experiences using my existing cards.

Comment: are you sure the issue is the brand of your card and not the chip-and-pin aspect of it?

Comment: I think I saw some Maestro-branded ATM cards in the US, they should work in Europe, too. The other big (but newer) network in Europe is V-Pay, but with that it's even harder to get a card outside Europe.

Comment: I am aware of chip and pin.  My chipped cards did not work as chip and pin.  I still had to sign.  Also, none of my cards worked at the vending machine or cafeteria.  Only debit card linked to my checking account worked at the train station.

Comment: @KateGregory I never looked specifically for that in the Netherlands, but in Germany Maestro cards are much more commonly accepted than MasterCard or other credit cards.

Comment: Aren't Maestro's debit cards only?

Comment: @JoErNanO Yes Maestro is only a debit card.

Comment: Masetro is a debit card which generally have lower per transaction fee (payable by the company running the vending machine) than credit cards.  This is probably why it refuses to accept mastercard - it wipes out any profit they can make from the sale.

Comment: @Phil what many people miss is that the transaction cost of dealing with cash can actually be as high as dealing with a credit card!

Comment: Most US banks are not using Chip and PIN, but only Chip and Signature. You _can_ find Chip and PIN cards in the US, but it will take some shopping. Note that Maestro is generally not accepted for payments in the US and usually only works for ATM withdrawals, so it probably will be far less useful than you think.

Comment: To everyone: It's an issue specific to the Netherlands (and to some extent Germany and perhaps a few other countries but definitely not the whole of Europe). A chip-and-pin Visa/Mastercard will be accepted virtually everywhere a local card is accepted in France but not in the Netherlands. Even European *or Dutch* MasterCard or Visa-branded cards have this problem so it goes beyond the usual chip-and-pin conundrum.

Comment: If you get a proper chip-and-pin credit card (e.g. a prepaid MasterCard as suggested by @Calchas), you should be able to use it in the new railway vending machines (with a €0.50 surcharge) and some supermarkets (IIRC, by Super de Boer and C1000 but not Albert Heijn or Jumbo). High-end shops and restaurants should be fine too. Not a complete solution as many places are still strictly Maestro/V-Pay-only but it should be at least somewhat easier.

Comment: no no no. don't try to open a bank account in another country. what a waste of time and effort. just get a proper chip and pin card. very few US banks offer them, but pentagon federal credit union and a few others do. no foreign trans fees at penfed, too.

Comment: Will US-issued MasterCard debit cards work with Maestro in Europe?

Comment: @QuantumMechanic no, a US MasterCard debit card will not work at Meastro-only terminals. It *will* work at places that accept credit cards though, which is most of the larger or more touristy shops.

Answer (score 6):

You can open a bank account in the Netherlands as a non-resident. I do not know the numbers but I doubt it is particularly cheap; I would be surprised if any free offering exists. However it can be done and I am sure an NL bank could get you a proper Maestro card.

Option 2 and I think a more sensible idea is to buy a Maestro/Mastercard pre-paid card. https://prepaid.yourmastercard.nl/ There are competing choices and sometimes you can pick them up in the supermarkets. I don't know about NL specifically I must admit.

Aside from this I would in your shoes talk to your US bank about obtaining a Visa or Mastercard with 0% forex fees and with a chip and pin facility. Such cards do exist. Visa and Mastercard is accepted in most places; actually "Maestro" is a brand of Mastercard. For other situations you can withdraw a few Euros.

I admit that vending machines are always a bit of an issue; even with a UK Mastercard I would guess only 70% of the time it works in Europe. I really don't know why mainland Europe makes it so hard. In Lisbon even the airport metro station doesn't accept foreign cards which, in my view, is utterly bizarre.

Comment: American Express cards are all issued as Chip and PIN... _except for US cardholders_ [who only get Chip and Signature](https://www.americanexpress.com/us/content/chip/signature.html). This is utterly senseless, but it's the current state of things.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I slipped in the AmEx reference because they are very good when they are accepted. I don't think a merchant is allowed to distinguish between chip and signature and chip and pin.

Comment: @calchas The link points to MasterCard prepaid card, not a Maestro card.

Comment: I have always heard that to open a bank account in the Netherlands you need a personal/tax number and to get that number you need to have the right to work in the Netherlands. If so, an American tourist will not be able to open such account. I am not sure though.

Comment: @Willeke I don't think it's a legal requirement and I vaguely recall seeing some offers geared towards non-residents. But as Calchas explained, it's usually more expensive, run-of-the-mill banking packages or super-cheap online offers won't be available without a regular income and tax number.

Comment: the point about american express is very much wrong. my US amex card does not work at any chip and pin terminals—found that out the hard way when trying to buy a subway ticket in barcelona. you need a proper chip and pin card, or you'll have to withdraw cash.

Comment: @sgroves Really? I was categorically assured the reverse by Amex. Did you try the 0000 pin trick? For now I shall delete that line.

Comment: @Willeke it just makes it easier for the bank but it is not a requirement. Google reveals several banks offering to help foreign customers.

Comment: Answers applicable to Europe in general do NOT always apply to the Netherlands in this matter. .nl adopted chip/pin debit cards long before the rest of the world, and historically have not been very interoperable with the rest of the world. This has started to change in the last few years, and international cards are increasingly accepted, but it can still be very hard to buy things there!

Comment: @SimonW That's not quite true, France introduced smart cards at about the same time, if not earlier and yet they are now much more interoperable. I think all POS terminals in the Netherlands are now fully EMV-compatible, it's just a matter of policy/transaction costs.

Comment: @relaxed thanks, I stand corrected! I haven't been in .nl much in the last ~year, I understand things have become much better. Although last time I tried, it was still impossible to buy a train ticket outside manned hours without either a Dutch bank account or the full price in coins.....

Comment: @SimonW Yes, it used to be pretty annoying! That has changed as well, with the roll-out of new vending machines for the OV-chipkaart system. But there is a surcharge…

Comment: @SimonW I was able to buy a train ticket with my U.S. bank issued debit card that is associated with my checking account.  I had to annoy the people behind me while I cycled through my cards finding one that worked.

Comment: @Calchas i wasn't aware of the 0000 pin trick. from reading on the web it looks like you're right, but that only works at certain types of terminals. personally, i still wouldn't travel to europe without my pentagon federal chip and pin card.

Comment: @sgroves Seems I was wrong about it! I shall leave the information out.

Answer (score 3):

This is no easy feat!  I have a similar challenge with travel to the Netherlands, and have never figured out a way to get a Maestro.

Best I have been able to do is get an account at Service Credit Union, who offer a V PAY card.  So far, I haven't found any places in NL that take Maestro and DON'T take V PAY.  But, Service CU will only maintain an account in US Dollars, and the exchange rate they offer on purchases (the US DoD exchange rate) is lousy.  Still, better than being embarrassed in front of a colleague in the cafeteria and unable to pay!

Answer (score 3):

September 2019: It appears to me that the PayPal Cash Card will work for maestro vending machine purchases (and ATM withdrawals).  I haven't tried it yet; I will update this post in November with results from my upcoming trip.

Full details on the card are at https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/ua/cashcard-agreement

Added November 2019: I didn't try any ATM withdrawals using the PayPal Cash Card, but it worked great for purchases in Amsterdam and Rotterdam: ticket automats for the train and the metro, restaurants, and even public toilets for the 1 euro entry fee.  There was one kebab stand where it wouldn't work but it worked everywhere else!

Comment: I have one of these cards. It doesn't have any logos printed on it except MasterCard, but it does support Maestro and ought to work. But be sure to contact PayPal before you leave the US so they can add a travel profile to the card.

Answer (score 2):

As a non-EU resident this indeed can be very difficult overall.
However, there are Dutch banks who service international clients/expats but also US residents. Maybe take a look here: https://www.abnamro.nl/en/personal/contact/index.html
See the non/resident/US section with contact details.
You will get a real Dutch Maestro card. Hope that helps!

Source: I'm Dutch.

Comment: As a former Dutch resident and American, I still have a bank account with ABN AMRO. I highly doubt they would let a foreigner open a new account. They already sent me a letter saying they will continue my current banking products but will not my permit me to open any new products.

Answer (score -1):

> [Note: This answer is outdated, but it is valuable as it adds the history of the Chipknip cards which could be confused for debit cards.  Chipknips cards were eliminated 2015-01-01]

You are confusing the multiple topics.

In banking cafeterias, there are special Dutch payment (or electronic cash) card systems in place. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chipknip
Because the banks introduced this new payment system, and the industry never adopted it, parking meters and banking cafeterias are the only ones who use it (and they disallow cash sales to try to keep their pet system relevant). The cards are the size format of credit cards and they have chips, but they are not banking/debit cards.

You will probably not get one of these cafeteria cards if you are not Dutch nor have a Dutch bank account. If you don't have a Dutch work permit and pay Dutch taxes, please just forget about this idea. Instead, continue to reimburse your coworkers with cash.

As for the Maestro card... Again I believe this is a red herring, but at least Maestro is a normal bank card provider. Try to open a Dutch bank account and see what they say.

Comment: Chipknip has been phased out and completely disabled on January 1st 2015 so that's not the issue. Parking meters now support “PIN” debit cards and (smart) phones. One cafeteria I know switched to contactless payments a couple of years ago.

Comment: I saw the Chipknip kiosk at the cafeteria and when I asked about it my colleagues told me it does not work anymore.  I would vote your answer down, but it is relevant information that Chipknip is no longer supported.

Comment: Vote my answer down please. My personal experience is from 2010 and this is clearly invalid.

Comment: @Doug: you can delete your own answer, no need for down votes